Generate C# code model for DataVerse entities
I would like to generate some code so i can interact with DataVerse tables from C#.
I have played around with the PAC CLI Modelbuilder and used that successfully. My issue is, that i am in a corporate environement with a lot of solutions, entites and fields.
For my contact, we have well over 600 columns. It is only a minor subset of those columns i am interested in in my C# classes.
How can i genereate models of the Dataverse entities in C#, but also controlling the included fields?
My hope was to find something that given a DataVerse solution could generate code for the included entities and fields in that solution

did you try with Early Bound Generator for XrmToolBox? https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/DLaB.Xrm.EarlyBoundGeneratorV2/

Give XrmToolBox plugin "Early-bound Template-based Code Generator" (by Ahmed Elsawalhy) a try.
In this plugin you select just the tables, columns and relationships you need. You can override class names (for the tables) and property names (for the columns and relationships).
There are quite a few options you can set which alter the way code is generated, but when that does not fit your needs, you can modify the T4 template that is the core of the generated output.
The template is complex, but I managed to modify it in such a way I can derive entity classes from a selective set of base classes: one for activities, one for business owned entities et cetera. This way I do not need to repeat common fields like CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, OwnerId etc. which keeps the generated code pretty concise.
All in all great flexibility because of it being based on T4 templates. We could even use it to generate TypeScript declarations.
